# Python getters, setters and manipulating fields

Tags: python, getter-setter

I am building a simple class which has some variables that only belong to an instance, for example a "created" field with epoch timestamp, and some other variables that are set when creating the instance. As exercise, want to do this in the **most** pythonic way possible. Furthermore, I want to have a function that prints the attributes, as json, so it can be used later on. So far, I have this:

```
import os
import uuid
import time


class Example:

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self._data = data
        self._id = self.id
        self._environment = self.environment
        self._created = self.created

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.environment == 'prd':
            self._data
        else:
            return None

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value

    @property
    def id(self):
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value

    @property
    def request(self):
        return self._request

    @request.setter
    def request(self, value):
        self._request = value

    @property
    def environment(self):
        return os.getenv('environment', 'dev')

    @environment.setter
    def environment(self, value):
        self._environment = value

    @property
    def created(self):
        return str(int(time.time()))

    @created.setter
    def created(self, value):
        self._created = value

    def to_json(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Output:

```
from example import Example

e = Example()
print(e.to_json())

# {'_data': None, '_id': '5f946b10-0e89-4d65-9f76-b9f15a81197d', '_environment': 'dev', '_created': '1592835056'}
```

Some doubts I have:

1. What is the best place to manipulate attributes? For example, I return a timestamp when self.created is called. And I manipulate the data attribute based upon another attribute. Is the getter the correct location for this kind of stuff?
2. Did I correctly assign the private variables to themselves within the **init**?
3. I need all the variables in a json for later processing, how do I output them in a json **without** them having an underscore?
4. How to accomplish the same thing using dataclasses?

Comment: Your code isn't working. You are missing some variables (`self.id` & `self.created`). Could you fix that please?

Comment: This also might be a good question to ask on the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your question 1. Yes in plain python, the best place to put code to execute when an attribute is read or written is a property. Alternatively you can create 'property-like' objects using the so-called [descriptor protoco](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)l (advanced).

For your question 2. Your init is not right as some variables that you use are not defined when you use them. Also the `created`, `environment` and `id` properties are not correctly written since if you use the setter, a new private attribute will be written (e.g. `_id`) but you do not use it in the getter. The "good" way to use a property is like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        if self._a is None:
            return "my_default_val"
        else:
            return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

e = Example()
print(e.a)
e.a = 2
print(e.a)
```

yields

```
my_default_val
2
```

For your question 3, the best for you is to learn how to use list comprehensions, dict comprehensions, etc. and to use this to dynamically filter your `vars(o)` (or `o.__dict__`, that's the same)

Now referring to your question 4. From my personal experience I would recommend not to use dataclasses, that is just a subset of `attrs`. You can use [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), or what seems more adapted to your use case where objects are mutable, [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/). Indeed `attrs` does not call validators/handlers on attribute change yet, and imposes quite a strict development philosophy (i.e. you can not use an `attr.ib` with *any* class since the class `__init__` and `__setattr__` are modified by `attrs`.

Here is how you can do with `pyfields`:

```
import os
import uuid
import time

from pyfields import field, get_field_values, make_init


class Example:
    # the various fields
    _data = field(default=None)
    environment = field(default_factory=lambda o: os.getenv('environment', 'dev'))
    id = field(default_factory=lambda o: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    created = field(default_factory=lambda o: str(int(time.time())))
    request = field()

    # create a default constructor if you do not need a custom one
    __init__ = make_init()

    # 'data' is a dynamic view that depends on 'environment': still need a property 
    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.environment == 'prd':
            return self._data
        else:
            return None

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value

    def to_json(self):
        dct = get_field_values(self, public_only=True)
        dct['data'] = self.data
        return dct


e = Example(request='hello')
print(e.to_json())
```

yields

```
{'environment': 'dev', 'id': '8f3c2f8f-ce36-4e69-bfb9-b044db83be84', 'created': '1592897458', 'request': 'hello', 'data': None}
```

Note that `get_field_values` does not return the contents of the `data` property. See [this feature request](https://github.com/smarie/python-pyfields/issues/71).

You can simplify this example further if needed, using `autofields` which removes some boilerplate in fields definitions and generates the constructor if none is present:

```
from pyfields import get_field_values, autofields

@autofields
class Example:
    # the various fields
    _data = None
    environment: str = os.getenv('environment', 'dev')
    id: str = str(uuid.uuid4())
    created: int = str(int(time.time()))
    request: str

    (... all the same than previously)
```

And finally, *if you need them*, you can add a nice `repr`, `eq`, `hash`, `dict` behaviour, etc. by using [`autoclass`](https://smarie.github.io/python-autoclass/). It will automatically detect that there are `fields` on the class, and you can use its `autofields` parameter to automatically create them:

```
from autoclass import autoclass

@autoclass(autofields=True)
class Example:
    # the various fields
    _data = None
    environment: str = os.getenv('environment', 'dev')
    id: str = str(uuid.uuid4())
    created: int = str(int(time.time()))
    request: str

    # data is a dynamic view that depends on the environment: need a property
    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.environment == 'prd':
            return self._data
        else:
            return None

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value

    def to_json(self):
        dct = dict(self)  # <--- note this: autoclass dict behaviour
        dct['data'] = self.data
        return dct

e = Example(request='hello')
print(repr(e))
```

yields:

```
Example(environment='dev', id='ee56cb2f-8a4a-48ac-9789-956f1eaea132', created='1592901475', request='hello', 'data': None)
```

Note: I'm the author of `pyfields` and `autoclass` ;)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, a very thorough explanation! I did a lot of functional programming in Python, but did not work that much with classes yet.